# Oracle Upgrade - Attach External Tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

We have just completed an 11g to 12c migration to a new server. There is a schema that didn't seem to come over that consists fully of external .dat files.

I can't seem to find a way to simple 'attach' these pre-existing (and moved from the old server) .dat files. Is the method to get this data back in to re-create the schema, table by table, pointing to the existing .dat files?

If so, is there a simple way to generate all the DDL statements for an entire schema of tables?

Thanks,
Wes

Comment: External table files contain data only, and no structural description. Of course you can not just simply attach them, you need to define the structure. Just generate the DDL statements from the old database on the old server.

Answer (score 0):

From researching further, and a bit from the comment on my question, I found that I needed to generate the DDL statements from the previous database. Once doing so, and setting the correct directory, everything worked perfectly.